# How to access 'fill' element of circle tag in sahi code

Tags: javascript, sahi

I want to access the fill element of circle tag in `<svg>` tag and assign the value to a variable.

fill value is `#08C65B`.

I tried with the below line but unable to get it:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].document.getElementsByTagName("circle")[0].getAttribute("fill")
```

var y = document.getElementsByTagName("svg"[0].document.getElementsByTagName("circle")[0].getAttribute("fill")

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works document.getElementsByTagName("circle")[0].getAttribute("fill"));

Answer (score 1):

```
let querySelector = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0]
let circleSelector = querySelector.getElementsByTagName("circle")[0]
let filledAttribute = circleSelector.getAttribute("fill")
```

or

Instead of using

```
document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].document.getElementsByTagName("circle")[0].getAttribute("fill")
```

Use

`document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].getElementsByTagName("circle")[0].getAttribute("fill")`

Answer (score 0):

Sahi has a [get attribute API](https://sahipro.com/docs/sahi-apis/fetch-apis.html#_getAttribute) and a [circle selector](https://sahipro.com/docs/sahi-apis/accessor-apis.html#_svg_circle)
So it should be possible to do a `_getAttribute(_svg_circle($selector), "fill")`

Comment: This works  document.getElementsByTagName("circle")[0].getAttribute("fill"));

Comment: Then maybe put this in an answer and accept it so the next one with the same problem can quickly find the solution